# How do you measure area in a discrete metric?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Given a discrete metric namely the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $1$ unless $x=y$ then the distance is $0$. Is it meaningful to define an area in this system? its clear that all triangles are equilateral and have the same are but how does this compare with the are of a square or a pentagon in this metric?

Comment: Metrics only deal with distances - what people think of as the "area" function is actually something called the Jordan measure. A space which has a measure, or an area function, is called a measure space. Bizarre though it may be, there is actually no relation between metric spaces and measure spaces. [There is however a way of constructing something called an outer measure for any metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure), though it probably won't resemble anything you could call an area for a discrete metric space.

Comment: @Wolfups: looks like a valid answer to me.